# Ios App take too much time to load from Splash to Home Page

Tags: iphone, ios8, appdelegate

My Application is getting too much time to move from Splash screen to Home page.Is it possible to reduce the loading time?In my homepage just i created a button alone nothing more than that.
      [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                           PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"AWAT3hD5dVL6gsNSUgIL9tY0geyGoa_Hmg81H7rgi3yKCO6sneWCyubqV4Wd"}];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBLoginView class];

```
/* Google Anayltics */
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-52277802-1"];


// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: Create splashController and navigate to your homeController using perfromSelector after delay in viewWillAppear!

Comment: Something must be taking time on the main thread, did you try to profile it with [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) ?

Comment: yes i tried with instrumentation but i cant able to find anything unwanted

Comment: thanks nabeel..My problem is reducing time not increasing time

Comment: what are you doing on the first view ? inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method ?

Comment: inside didfinishlaunching options i have load payment and facebook key integration.i have updated the code